# Turn off NVIDIA on Windows 8.1 Bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, windows, gpu

Has there be a successful attempt to turn off the NVIDIA graphic card and use the Intel one?

I know that in Linux, it is possible to turn off one graphic card and use the other (using vgaswitcheroo).

I am running Windows 8.1 Bootcamp on MB Pro 10.1 and experience overheating due to this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to disable the nVidia graphics card, you can do the following:

1. Reboot into safe mode. If you don't know how to, refer to [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode) for more information. Make sure that the Mac is configured to boot from Windows in the Boot Camp Control Panel.
2. After booting into safe mode, open Device Manager by pressing Win+R, and then typing devmgmt.msc.
3. Expand Display Adapters
4. Right click on the nVidia driver and select Disable. **MAKE SURE THAT YOU DO NOT DISABLE THE INTEL HD GRAPHICS OR IRIS PRO**
5. Reboot the Mac into Windows 8.1
6. If it boots normally, great. If it screws up, do steps 1-3 and select enable.

Note that this will **DISABLE** your discrete graphics, so that means that you cannot use it until you re enable it in Device Manager.

Comment: On my late 2013 MBP 15" there is only the nvidia 750m

Comment: Same here, 2012 MBP A1398, only NVidia

Comment: It seems in fact that there is no way to use the Intel and disable the NVidia for several MBP models